# How does std::unique_ptr work when it goes out of scope after the object it owns has been manually deleted?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I may not have worded the title correctly, but it is easier to explain in the following example, and then perhaps someone can edit the title.

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> // for std::unique_ptr

class Resource
{
public:
    Resource() { std::cout << "Resource acquired\n"; }
    ~Resource() { std::cout << "Resource destroyed\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Resource* res = new Resource;
    std::unique_ptr<Resource> res1(res); // Resource created here
    delete res;

    std::cout << "res1 is " << (static_cast<bool>(res1) ? "not null\n" : "null\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
$ ./a.out 
Resource acquired
Resource destroyed
res1 is not null
Resource destroyed
```

We created a dynamically allocated resource, and then created a unique pointer (res1) who owns this resource. The unique pointer allows us to not worry about having to manually delete the resource.

But let's suppose we manually delete the resource anyway (without setting it to null after) as in the above code. Then when res1 goes out of scope, wouldn't it be trying to delete something that has already been deallocated?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the `unique_ptr` will try to delete the object after it goes out of scope in this case. In fact, the example you've shown above is a perfect way of illustrating one of the key properties of `unique_ptr`: if you have a resource managed by `unique_ptr`, you should not attempt to manage that resource yourself outside of the `unique_ptr`. After all, the contract with `unique_ptr` is "the `unique_ptr` owns the resource exclusively," so if you take that resource and deallocate it yourself, you're violating the contract.

In other words, what `unique_ptr` does is a bit stronger than "allowing us to not worry about having to manually delete the resource." Rather, it assumes complete and exclusive responsibility for managing the resource.

Similar issues can arise with, say, `shared_ptr`, which assumes that all ownership of the resource is shared across the different `shared_ptr`s to a resource.

If you want to explicitly free the resource before the function returns, use the `reset` function:

```
res1.reset(); // Cleans up the resource.
```

Comment: What I fail to understand is how this code doesn't throw a seg fault. After all, the unique pointer is deleting something I have already deleted. Shouldn't that cause a seg fault?

Comment: If you deallocate the same resource twice, you get *undefined behavior*, which means that there is no guarantee whatsoever about what can happen. It might segfault, or it might corrupt the state of the memory manager and lead to all sorts of terrible things downstream, or it may be totally harmless. Such is the wonderful world of C++. :-)

Comment: @user308485 "*What I fail to understand is how this code doesn't throw a seg fault*" - because there is nothing for it to segfault on! There is no real access of the object's memory being performed. The object's `this` pointer is not being used for anything in your code. Add some data members to the `Resource` class, especially non-trivial types like `std::string`, etc, and then try to access them after calling `delete`, such as in `~Resource()`. The code will be much more likely to crash.